# Unable to parse json and unset array with condition jquery Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I am working with jquery and json,I want to unset array if condition not match using jquery,
i want to unset array according to range selector using jquery
I want to unset array ($rec) if input "rating" is less thane max value(store in database/mysql)
For example if i give rating 8 then question(ques_id="18" should be unset/remove from array)

Right now i am unable to parse json using loop in php,Here is my json ()

```
[{"ques_id":"15","question":"Lorem Ipsum","min_value:"NULL","max_value:"NULL","show_quesId:"18",","isSubquestion":null}
[{"ques_id":"18","question":"Lorem Ipsum2","min_value:"1","max_value:"7","isSubquestion":1}
[{"ques_id":"19","question":"Lorem Ipsum3","min_value:"8","max_value:"10","isSubquestion":1}
```

I tried with following code but not working(specially cant parse my json,showing me object,object)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#next1").click(function(){
     var rating =$("#name").val(); // value from "range"(input type range)
                var data = <?php echo json_encode($rec); ?>; //(codeigniter array,containing Question and subquestion)
                var nd = JSON.stringify(data);
                
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        alert(data[i].PageName);
                        if(rating<data[i].max_value)  // checking whether given rating less than max_value (database)
                            { 
                                    if(data[i].isSubquestion!=NULL)
                                    {
                                        //unset this subquestion
                                    }
                            }
                    });

     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I noticed some bad JSON Syntax: `"min_value:"NULL"` You're missing the closing quote, preceding `:`. Correct the JSON and it should parse properly.

Comment: @Twisty: that is by mistake written,kindly tell me where i am wrong ?

Comment: You are missing the closing quote, on a number of them: `[{"ques_id":"15","question":"Lorem Ipsum","min_value:"NULL","max_value:"NULL","show_quesId:"18",","isSubquestion":null}`. it should be: `[{"ques_id":"15","question":"Lorem Ipsum","min_value":"NULL","max_value":"NULL","show_quesId":"18","isSubquestion":"NULL"}]` It's also not clear why you have multiple Arrays.